# Apex outputtext value attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce, outputtext

This is a generic question

```
apex:outputText value="{**0**,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}"
```

What I wanted to know is what is the 0 in value used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `0` tells you which argument index to merge in. So usually, you just have one argument, and merging it in uses the 0-index parameter. But you might for some reason have multiple arguments (each represented by an `<apex:param>`).

```
<apex:outputText value="{0} {1, date, MM}">
    <apex:param value="test" />
    <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

As represented by the above example, you can merge multiple arguments into one format string. It is very similar behavior to the `String.format` method in `Apex`, though I don't believe you can do date formatting that way.

Answer (score 1):

The value attribute on "apex:outputText" is  a valid format. It must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice.

For more info please check this url

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm?search_text=apex:outputtext

As per String.formate in Java and apex you can say.....

under documented Apex String API i.e.

```
String formattedString = String.format(String template, List<String> arguments)
```

`String.format(..)` is again based on Java MessageFormat class, its documentation says :

Treat the current string as a pattern that should be used for substitution in the same manner as apex:outputText.

Nice part of this String API is that it supports basic text substitution for ex.

```
// Create a Template String, that has tokens of form {index} 

String templateString = 'Hello {0}, Good to see you in {1}';

// String argument list or array matching each {index} in Template String.

String[] arguments = new String[] {'Ram' , 'India'};

// Call String.format() to get the token replaced

String formattedString = String.format(templateString, arguments);

System.debug(formattedString);
```

> // output : Hello Ram, Good to see you in India

Bad part about this String API is it only supports String arguments for token replacement. Though both Java’s MessageFormat and Visuaforce apex:outputText tag accept non-string arguments like Date, Datetime & Currency and are capable of doing very smart formatting with them. For ex. in visualforce one can format date using outputText as follows.

```
<apex:outputText value="The formatted time right now is: 
    {0,date,yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z}">
   <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

> output: The formatted time right now is: 2004.11.20 AD at 23:49:02 GMT

Similar Java example with more options would be

Object[] arguments = {

```
 new Integer(7),

 new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),

 "a disturbance in the Force"
```

};

String result = MessageFormat.format(

```
 "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",

 arguments);
```

> output: At 12:30 PM on Jul 3, 2053, there was a disturbance

```
       in the Force on planet 7.
```

Sadly, if you try to do something similar with Apex it always fails for StringException.

Comment: Gaurav -- please use the code formatting tools to reformat your answer